# Wide Frame Subsetting in R

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I have a large data set that has scenarios like the following:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable =c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
 Day1=c("1", "1", "-1", "1", "1", "-1", "1", "1", "1"),
 Day2=c("1", "1", "-1", "1", "1", "-1", "1", "1", "1"),
 Day3=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "-1", "1", "1", "1"),
 Day4=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "-1"),
 Day5=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "-1")),
 class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -9L))
```

I want to create 3 tables. The first keeps all "Variable" duplicates that have 2 or more consecutive negative numbers prior to Day 3 and would look like the following:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable =c("A", "A", "A"), 
 Day1=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day2=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day3=c("1", "1", "1"),
 Day4=c("1", "1", "1"),
 Day5=c("1", "1", "1")),
 class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -3L))
```

The second would include all with negatives on the Day 3:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable =c("B", "B", "B"), 
 Day1=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day2=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day3=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day4=c("1", "1", "1"),
 Day5=c("1", "1", "1")),
 class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -3L))
```

And third, all with 2 or more consecutive numbers prior to what would be Day 6:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable =c("C", "C", "C"), 
 Day1=c("1", "1", "-"),
 Day2=c("1", "1", "1"),
 Day3=c("1", "1", "1"),
 Day4=c("1", "1", "-1"),
 Day5=c("1", "1", "-1")),
 class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: in the 3rd df, why is A not included?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# Define a helper-function to count -1's on selected days
sum_days <- function(.df, n) {
  vars <- paste0("Day", n)
  rowSums(.df[vars] == -1)
}

# Now mark which rows go where:
grouped_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    DF1 = sum_days(., 1:2) >= 2,
    DF2 = sum_days(., 3) == 1,
    DF3 = sum_days(., 1:5) >= 2
  ) %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("DF")), any) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Now you have two options - you can either leave the data frame as-is, and use the `DF1`, `DF2` and `DF3` filters to mark which rows you're using for subsequent analyses, or you can explicitly create your new data frames:

```
df1 <- grouped_df[grouped_df $DF1,]
df2 <- grouped_df[grouped_df $DF2,]
df3 <- grouped_df[grouped_df $DF3,]
```

If you aren't familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it's a way to linearize the code.  All it does it call the next function with the result of the previous function as the first argument.